# Keeping Tasker Plugin Alive in Background

Tags: tasker, background-process

I'm experiencing a little difficulty in keeping a Tasker plugin alive in background. The name of the plugin is called Tasker Process Running (KC) and it gets killed from background by Android's LMK once the RAM gets too busy.

I am planning to use Tasker to keep it alive in the background using an "If" - "Else" loop. What are the proper step-by-step method to do this?

Comment: Have a look a this : http://www.pocketables.com/2013/05/beginners-guide-to-tasker-part-1-5-tasker-basics-new-ui.html

Comment: @Maxime Thanks for the reply, but wasn't the answer I was looking for. I know the basics of Tasker, I just need the steps to specifically setup Tasker Process Running (KC). But, thanks for your reply anyway. =)